# fgetc() exits on second input?

Tags: c, fgetc

I was experimenting with C's `fgetc()` and ran into a strange problem.
I typed the following code below:

```
    int answer = 0;

    printf("Input1\n");

    answer = fgetc(stdin);
    printf("%c\n", answer);

    printf("Input2\n");
    answer = fgetc(stdin);
    printf("%c\n", answer);
```

However, every time I enter a value other than a space, this happens:

```
 Input1
 1
 1
 Input2 # It doesn't wait for my input here
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've tried flushing `stdin` and I've also tried using `rewind` on `stdin`. However, none of these work.

Comment: After the first character, there is a newline waiting to be read, so `fgetc()` doesn't need to wait for more input.  Consider reading lines with standard C [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) and then parse the input.

Comment: Classic mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type in `1` followed by enter, there is `\n` char at the end of input. The second `fgetc` will read the `\n` character.

For debugging (as suggested in comments) you can replace `printf("%c\n", answer)` with

```
printf("Got %d (%c)\n", answer, (isprint(answer) ? answer : '.'));
```

The result should be:

```
Input1
1
Got 49 (1)
Input2
Got 10 (.) <- new line
```

Comment: `%c` is OK as a format specifier; using `%d` may be better for debugging, but `%c` isn't automatically wrong (indeed, it is often, even usually, right!).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The asker declared `int answer = 0;`

Comment: And?  That's the correct type to receive the value from `fgetc()` because it returns an `int`.  It has to return an `int` because it returns every possible `char` value (converted to `unsigned char` and then `int`) plus one exceptional value, EOF, which is negative (usually but not necessarily `-1`).  So a `char` can't hold that many different values, and `fgetc()` therefore returns an `int`.  Yes, the code should check that it didn't get `EOF` before printing with `%c`, but using `%c` to print an `int` containing a character is fine, and normal.

Comment: Indeed, if you take a `char` variable and pass it to `printf()`, it will be converted to `int` automatically, because all the arguments in the ellipsis section of a variadic function like `printf()` undergo default argument conversions — `char` and `short` values are converted to `int` and `float` values are converted to `double`.  It's why there was no need for separate format specifiers for `float` and `double`; the values passed to `printf()` were always `double`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I got confused. I see your point about the usefulness in debugging.

Comment: For debugging, printing it in both formats is good: `printf("Got %d (%c)\n", answer, (isprint(answer) ? answer : '.'));` works quite well, printing a dot when the character isn't printable.  Or you can avoid printing the character notation when it isn't printable.  Or …